# Is it possible to use JWT alongside SignalR?

Tags: asp.net, xamarin, signalr, jwt, owin

Our project is using `SignalR` over `ASP.NET OWIN (full framework)`, and clients are mobile apps based on `Xamarin`. Authentication is done based on `JWT`. It is needed that we protect `SignalR` hubs against anonymous access, then find out user name of the connection.

Is it possible to `SignalR` to work with `JWT`? If yes, how?

`SignalR`'s own protection is based on cookies not `JWT`. Also we can't afford to use query strings to pass the **token** due to deployment that is not HTTPS.

Comment: I have a vague memory of using OAuth middleware for the task, sort of like this http://blog.marcinbudny.com/2014/05/authentication-with-signalr-and-oauth.html?m=1

Comment: @orhtej2 I read the article. Thanks for sharing. But that did not worked for me. If I put [Authorize] on hub method they never be authorized

Comment: You can inherit from `AuthorizeAttribute` to enforce some custom validation rules. It's all about setting WHAT Authorize is meant to read.